# Block installed app in android like applock app

Tags: android

I have to block installed application when the application is launched like applock android application.

I got list of installed application.I don't know how to block those applications.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

            Log.d("Package", "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d("Launch",
                    "Launch Activity :"
                            + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));           

    }
```

I tried to kill app by using process id.It does n't work

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(10096);
```

Comment: did you get any answer for it?